# Storage with sqlite in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, fragment

I wrote a program that reads a data from editText and then saves it
I ran this program once in activity and it worked correctly but on fragment it gives  error
please help me

my fragment

```
public class fragment_create extends Fragment {
database database=new database(getContext());
public ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView listView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create,container,false);
    EditText editText=view.findViewById(R.id.enter_your_job);
    Button button=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_job);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data=editText.getText().toString();
            database.insertmodel(data);
            editText.setText("");
            Log.i("amir", "data is save");
        }
    });
    return view;
   }
```

my database class

```
    public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String databasename="database.db";
private static final int version=1;

public database( Context context) {
    super(context, databasename, null, version);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query="CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(query);
    Log.i("amir", "data is create");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
    public void insertmodel(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name",name);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert("table1",null,contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        Log.i("amir", "data is create");
}
```

}

please help me for this problem

Comment: Consider adding the error message as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue is occurring specifically in a `Fragment`, it's possible that the `Context` passed to the `database` class is causing the problem.

I would suggest instead of initiating `database` on top level, do it inside `onCreateView()` method. and replace `getContext()` with `getActivity()` like below.

```
public class fragment_create extends Fragment {
//keep other things as it is

database database;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create,container,false);
    .
    .
    .
    database = new database(getActivity()); // get the context of parent activity
    .
    .
    .
    return view;
   }
}
```

> Please note that I have mentioned important things only, so keep the other things as it is and only change the code I mentioned in the above code block.